# How to shuffle a folder of images that have been converted to tensors

Tags: python, image, pytorch

My code:

```
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/dataset/test', batch_size = 8, shuffle=True)
```

The folder above consists of 2 subfolders with images, which have been transformed into tensors. However I can't get them to be shuffled, I'm trying to shuffle all images in both folders. How do I get this to work? Running this line doesn't even shuffle the data within each subfolder.

Comment: You should be passing a `Dataset` object to `DataLoader`, not a path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the data as a Dataset before passing it to DataLoader:

```py
from torch import utils.data as data_utils
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

data_path = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/dataset/test'

data = datasets.ImageFolder(root=data_path, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
data_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(data, batch_size=8, shuffle=True)
```